# Asus X556U HDD keeps turn on then off in sleep

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, sleep

I just bought an ASUS X556U laptop and installed a legal Windows10 10. Everything works properly but when it goes to sleep or close it, everything turns of except the HDD. It starts to turn off then on periodically. I've searched for the problem but I did not find any solution. Do you have any tips what I should try?

PS: Sorry for my grammer mistakes

Comment: As I know, For both S3 (Sleep, or Standby) and S4 (hibernate) sleep modes, the hard disk is turned off, along with anything else that isn't needed. Please open CMD as admin and see if your HDD is listed on S3 / S4 supported: powercfg /devicequery S3_supported OR powercfg /devicequery S4_supported. I have another question, if you scheduler any backup on your PC, I consider the scheduler wake up the HDD to do the backing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Settings > System > Power & sleep. Click on Additional power settings on the right.

In Power Options click on Change when the computer sleeps (on the left). Click on Change advanced power settings. Check the Hard disk and Sleep settings and change them if needed. Click OK if you make changes.

Comment: Thanks! I've already tried it but last time I set it to 1 minute, now with "never" it works. By the way for a strange reason I thought it means hdd will never turn off. So SOLUTION: SET TIME TO NEVER!